# Duplicate new object after deleting the previous one

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a simple game in which when a character comes into contact with an element he removes it and another object appears elsewhere:

Below is the code how I add and remove an item from the game

```
void Start()
{
    Application.targetFrameRate = 60;
    CreateElementPlasticMetal(10, 40);
}

private void OnControllerColliderHit(ControllerColliderHit hit)
{
    if(hit.gameObject.tag == "PLASTICMETAL")
    {
        Destroy(hit.gameObject);
        CreateElementPlasticMetal(10, 40);
    }
}

private void CreateElementPlasticMetal(int startX, int endX)
{
    Vector3 positionObject = new Vector3(Random.Range(startX, endX), 10f, 6f);

    GameObject elementGame = Instantiate(PlasticMetalPrefab, positionObject, transform.rotation);
    elementGame.tag = "PLASTICMETAL";
    Collider elementCollider = elementGame.AddComponent<BoxCollider>();
    Rigidbody elementRigidBody = elementGame.AddComponent<Rigidbody>();

    elementGame.transform.localScale = new Vector3(20f, 20f, 20f);
}
```

The problem is that over time, many items are added at once. Shouldn't the game delete itself and add one more?

Comment: BTW I would urge you to include the collider/etc and the scale ON THE PREFAB.  Perhaps make another prefab named PlasticMetalPrefabWithStuff which includes all of that.

Comment: I would suggest looking into a concept called *Object Pooling.*

Comment: Do you really need to destroy and recreate, or could you just *move* the existing one?

Answer (score 0):

1. Try the usual **quick fix** of `DestroyImmediate`. Depending on the situation, this works even during physics.
2. **Wait until the next frame** to create the new one.

.

```
if (hit.gameObject.tag == "PLASTICMETAL")
    {
    StartCoroutine(CleanAndNew(hit.gameObject))

IEnumerator CleanAndNew(GameObject x)
    {
    Destroy(x);
    yield return null;
    // in Unity3D, that essentially means "wait one frame"
    CreateElementPlasticMetal( ...
```

The "next frame" idea is one technique for avoiding the problem you face.

## Just a note ...

*unrelated: you are suffering a classic game programming problem.  You may be creating the new one, touching the collider of the player (or whatever it is).  In fact when you choose a random position for the new one, you have to exclude any areas where it may land in contact.  It's not so easy to do this properly.  (Beware of an indeterminate algorithm which can run forever.)*

Comment: `Destroying GameObjects immediately is not permitted during physics trigger/contact, animation event callbacks, rendering callbacks or OnValidate. You must use Destroy instead.
UnityEngine.Object:DestroyImmediate(Object)
PlayerController:OnControllerColliderHit(ControllerColliderHit)`. It does not work. I've already checked. I've included almost all the code

Comment: @DevNet - fair enough, sometimes it works!  I will put in another answer for you.

Comment: I added all the code https://pastebin.com/Eb0HcYMJ . There's still something wrong. How it is now: The object disappears from the game board. This object remains in the Hierarchy and another one appears and two objects appear on the game board

Comment: Dev, I've gioven the basic answer and unfortunately don't have time tgo look in to the code more!  Hopefully someone else can!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it but you can try disabling the gameobjects you want to destory and then destroy it in another frame. Try this:

```cs
private void OnControllerColliderHit(ControllerColliderHit hit)
{
    if(hit.gameObject.tag == "PLASTICMETAL")
    {
        hit.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        Destroy(hit.gameObject);
        CreateElementPlasticMetal(10, 40);
    }
}
```

Comment: Generally it's really easier to just wait a frame to make the new one, from the same code.